# cp_errordocument.shtml (port 443) wont let me access my wordpress dashboard

Tags: mysql, wordpress, hosting, cpanel, http-status-code-403

Everytime I try to login to my wordpress dashboard I keep on getting this error. I have tried both login details and softaculous login button but I still get the same error.
The site itself has also been giving me this error so I cant view it.
The error is as follows:
"
403 Forbidden
Please forward this error screen to grocerydrive.co.za's WebMaster.

Access is forbidden to the requested page:
domainname.com/cp_errordocument.shtml (port 443)
"

--
**Hence domainname.com is not the actual domain name**

This website is an income for a charity and they heavily rely on this site.
Please can anyone assist?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it seemed to be these lines of code that I had to disable the following lines in the wp-config.php:

#add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );
#add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );

As they were causing the issue.